# Jquery append html to just above the last paragraph

Tags: jquery

My Jquery:

```
$("#leftmain").append("something");

<div id="leftmain">
// append text here
<p id="loading" >Loading ...</p>
</div>
```

How do I append the text just above the paragraph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.before()`:

```
$('#loading').before("<div>something</div>");
```

Which will add the new node just before the `#loading` element: http://api.jquery.com/before

Or you can use `.prepend()`:

```
$('#leftmain').prepend("<div>something</div>");
```

Which will add the new HTML as the first child element of the `#leftmain` element: http://api.jquery.com/prepend

Here is a demo showing how each of the methods I suggest work: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/ndqpp/

### Update

To fade-in dynamically created content you can set it to hidden by default then call `.fadeIn()` on the new content:

```
$('#leftmain').prepend("<div style='display : none'>something</div>").children().first().fadeIn(500);
```

or if you use `.before()`:

```
$('#loading').before("<div style='display : none'>something</div>").prev().fadeIn(500);
```

Comment: @Railsbeginner See the **update** to my answer for how to fade the content in.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) instead of `.append()`. Prepend will insert your content at the beginning of the selected element, instead of at the end.

```
$("#leftmain").prepend("Something");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var cur = $('#leftmain').html();
$('#leftmain').html('your_text' + cur);
```

Comment: `.prepend()` is better than this solution.